# Getting 'builtin_function_or_method object is not iterable' on file upload

Tags: django, file-upload

I am unable to upload the file. I am getting

`Type error builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`

***models.py***

```
class seeker(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birthday = models.DateField()

class Upload(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Seekers)
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to ='resume', blank = True, null = True)
```

***forms.py***

```
class SeekersForm(forms.Form):
    resume = forms.FileField(label = 'Select a file',help_text = 'max.3 MB')
```

***views.py***

```
def List(request):

    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SeekersForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():

            #id = User.object.get(id)
            newdoc = Seekers.objects.get(user_id)
            newdoc.resume =Upload(resume = request.FILES['resume'])
            newdoc.save()

            #seekers_edit = Seekers.objects.get(id) 
            #seekers_edit.resume = Seekers(resume = request.FILES['resume'])
            #seekers_edit.save()

            #Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        form = SeekersForm() # A empty, unbound form

    #Load documents for the list page   
    seekers = Seekers.objects.all()

    #Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response('list.html',{'seekers':seekers,'form':form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Check the line `newdoc = Seekers.objects.get(user_id)`. Is `Seekers` a valid model? I'm assuming it is, but it's not shown in your `models.py` snippet.

Comment: Exactly where is the error occurring? What is the traceback? As I've said many times before, all that traceback information is shown for a reason. Please post it.

Comment: The error is because the syntax of `.get()` would be `.get(pk=user_id)`, not just `.get(user_id)`. There are other problems with your code, however — see below.

Comment: i have added seeker model into the code & thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say where your problem is, but I think the following line of code is the main problem:

```
newdoc.resume =Upload(resume = request.FILES['resume'])
```

You have to save a file in a FileField explicitly before you save the entire model instance. Also, if you have a ForeignKey field in one of your models and you want to assign it an instance of another model, please save that instance first before you do the assignment. Without knowing your `Seekers` model, all I can do is guessing what might help you. Something like the following might get you started:

```
your_file = request.FILES['resume']
upload_instance = Upload()
upload_instance.resume.save(name=your_file.name, content=your_file, save=False)
upload_instance.user = ... # Here goes an instance of your Seekers model
upload_instance.save() # Here you save the whole instance of your Upload model
```

Also, please note the following:

1. Your model `Seekers` should rather be named `Seeker` using the singular, not the plural. This should generally be like that with all your models.
2. Python functions should always start with a lowercase letter, i.e. `list` instead of `List`. However, this name is a bad choice here anyway, because a function called `list` is already present in Python's standard library.

Please take a closer look at Django's documentation. It's all in there what you need to know. I recommend you to read especially these sections:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#filefield

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/files/file/

Comment: but i am getting error upload_instance = Seeker.object.get(id) getting an error builtin_method or function object is not iterateable

Comment: Sure, because you obviously neither read supervacuo's nor my answer carefully enough. Read them again.

Answer (score 0):

Problems in your code:

- Your form definition duplicates information from your model — just use [`forms.ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/) (with `exclude` so as not to display the `user` field)
- As currently pasted, `newdoc = Seekers.objects.get(user_id)` will raise a `TypeError` (`'foo' object is not iterable`); [`.get()` accepts keyword parameter filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get), not anything else.
- Accessing `request.FILES['resume']` manually isn't necessary or recommended

So, in short, you're almost there; just let Django forms do more of the work for you:

```
# forms.py
class SeekerForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Seeker

# views.py    
def seeker_list(request):
    # Opinions are divided as to whether it's ever appropriate to 
    # modify the database like this on a GET request, but it seems
    # to make sense here
    seeker = Seekers.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SeekerForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=seeker)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        form = SeekerForm(instance=seeker)

    seekers = Seekers.objects.all()

    #Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response('list.html', {
        'seekers':seekers,
        'form':form
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

It's not clear what the significance (if any) of the commented-out sections of your code is — I've assumed you always want to modify the current user's `Seeker`, but if not then adapt as appropriate.